# Most expensive stackable item that can be traded, bought, and sold

Tags: dark-souls-3

Since I can't get summoned for Darkmoon I'm farming knights in anor londo like crazy, and I'm up to 2.5 million souls w/ like 5 concords (450ish item discovery) - this sucks.

Anyway, on my other lower level dude I'd ideally like to buy a stackable item with all these souls, and trade it via a friend to another one of my characters that can then sell the item for souls.

Anyone have any idea what the ideal item is to do such a thing with?

Comment: Has the character buying the stacked items given the Shrine Handmaid the Dragon Chaser's Ashes? Titanite mats seem perfect for this.

Comment: @pushasha can titanite be traded? i was under the impression that upgrade materials could not be traded across characters

Comment: Dang, you're right! Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you plan only to transfer souls, look for items which cost 500 and could be sold for 100 (5:1 seems to be the best possible rate), some of these are:

- Homeward bone (stocking with these also allows you to trade Coiled Sword Fragment for Titanite Slab without regrets),
- Rotten Pine Resin,
- Duel Charm,
- Undead Hunter Charm,
- Charcoal Pine Resin,
- Kukri (costs 50, could be sold for 10).

I think best investment for **current character** will be Titanite Chunks for 13000 souls each from Shrine Handmaid (both Titanite Scale and Twinking Titanite are more expensive, but mostly useless in my opinion - as boss weapons suck). Unfortunately, these cannot be traded.

Beside upgrade mats it makes sense to stock with all useful consumables - Green Blossoms, different resins, firebombs.

Answer (score 2):

Black Firebombs (both normal and roped variants) can be purchased from Patches for 300 souls, and sold for 100, giving them a 3:1 ratio

Answer (score 1):

The best purchasable item for transferring souls via trade is Homeward Bones.

They can be purchased for 500 each and sold for 100, and most importantly, have a Held limit of 99. There are many items with a 5:1 ratio, but most have low limits, so only a paltry amount can be handed over on each summon session.

For the price of 49,500 souls, you can transfer 9,900 souls in a single transaction via 99 Homeward Bones.

Blooming Purple Moss Clumps are equally as good as Homeward Bones (5:1 ratio, 99 Held). However, they are not available for unlimited purchase from the Shrine Handmaid until given the Excrement-covered Ashes. They are also dropped by the little crabs in the Catacombs of Carthus, so you can save some money by farming from them.

The second best item is Purging Stones (when bought from the Shrine Handmaid after giving Yuria's Ashes). These are bought for 3,000 souls and sold for 500 souls, making for a 6:1 ratio. This means they are a worse investment than Homeward Bones, but they too have a 99 Held limit and sell for 5x more than Homeward Bones. Large amounts of souls can be transferred faster this way, but you will lose more souls from the worse ratio.

For the price of 297,000, you can transfer 49,500 souls in a single transaction via 99 Purging Stones.